# JQuery AJAX, Deleting from a table when successful and keeping when unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'html',
  url: "submitreef" + "?id=" + $id,
  timeout: 5000,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    Materialize.toast('Deleted', 4000);
  },
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    Materialize.toast('Error, we could not delete the campaign, please try again later', 4000);
    $error = 'true';
  }
});
}

if ($error != '') {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}

});
```

My problem is that when a button is pressed to delete a record from a table it works flawlessly, but when the error function is called it does not delete, I am trying to fix this, and my attempted fix is above, but it didn't work.

If you tried to delete it twice and there were 2 errors, it would then work, but that of course isn't very useful.

I really hope someone could help me out.

Many thanks.

Comment: the `error` function of jQuery Ajax is only called if there is a server side error. so there may be some error on server side delete code.

Comment: I know, on the chance that it gets called, I don't want to delete the row from the table clientside, so basically, if the error function gets called the  $(this).closest('tr').remove(); shouldn't be run

Comment: that is because you are trying to check the `var $error` outside after ajax call and it would always be called before the ajax call is completed, and will always be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var trToRemove = $(this).closest('tr');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'html',
    url: "submitreef"+"?id="+$id,
    timeout: 5000,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        trToRemove.remove();
        Materialize.toast('Deleted', 4000);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        Materialize.toast('Error, we could not delete the campaign, please try again later', 4000);
    }
});
```

so its basically the problem with asynchronous ajax. your `error` or `success` gets called only when it receives a response from server. but your following code gets executed before that.

```
if ($error != '') {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

so thats why its producing unexpected removal of the element.

as suggested by @MuhammadOmerAslam You must also keep in mind that success callback may get called but your actual data has not been deleted. so its better to return something after you deleted the data on server side and compare it in your success handler before removing the `tr` element.

if you return `"success"` after data is deleted on server side then your success function should look something like the following:

```
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    if(data=='success'){
        trToRemove.remove();
        Materialize.toast('Deleted', 4000);
    }else{
        Materialize.toast('Error, we could not delete the campaign, please try again later', 4000);
    }
},
```

Comment: this still won't solve the problem the error function will be triggered for the `500 internal server error` or `404 Not Found` , what if the DB is unable to connect? how would you verify if the value was actually removed from the table @JohnKonen

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam will it not get server side error if DB is unable to connect?

Comment: try to create a simple page with ajax call to a PHP file and provide the wrong pass to the user you will see it won't go to the error callback but the `success` because according to doc `error` **will be called if the request fails**. and request failure has nothing to do with db connection, you can even add a type parsing error it would still go to `success`, add an alert inside the `success` callback like `alert(data)` and it will show you the connection error as text response there

Comment: if you could return json that would be more helpful as you can send from the server a json like `data:{success: false, error_details:'Failed to connect to databases',}` and use it like `if(data.sucess){//remove row}else{alert(data.error_details);}`